# Sudden ImportError: cannot import name "QtCore" from "PyQt5"

Tags: python, pyqt5, importerror

I have build a program with PyQt5 as the GUI. The program was working perfectly just moments ago. But, when I ran the program recently I got this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtCore' from 'PyQt5' (/Users/Febin.J/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/Planner Builder/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/__init__.py)
```

The strange thing is I did not change any code. Just all of a sudden I keep getting this error.

I ran the program from VS Code and the Mac Terminal but still get the same error.

This is where the error is occuring:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
```

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: make sure that your vs code selected the right version for python.

Answer (score 3):

Solved: The file was corrupted. I tried reinstalling pyqt:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall PyQt5
```

It works like before now.

Thanks to u/socal_nerdtastic on Reddit for the solution

Comment: Please note that questions caused by problems that make them not reproducible are considered off topic and should be deleted, not answered, as it's very unlikely that anybody would find them useful in any way.

Comment: @musicamante Well it appear to have happened to me too. Thank you OP! You saved me a lot of time

Comment: @RIJIK "very unlikely" doesn't mean *never ever*. The point is, if we provided answer for *any very unlikely* situation, especially if caused by user mistake or file corruption we could know anything about, StackOverflow would become a galaxy of unnecessary questions (infinitely more than it is right now) with a billion of unlikely answers. That's not the scope of SO, you got "lucky", as you found a single question/answer that reflected your case, but, truth is, trying to reinstall a library that just stopped working is just one of the basic option one should think about.